# Change the $parent_file of a plugin page

Tags: plugins, admin-menu

I have a plugin that has 3 pages. One of those pages, I don't want displayed in the admin menu (working), but when a user is on that page, I want the plugin menu to be active.

I'm using the `parent_file` filter, but it isn't working.

I've had a look in the core, and alghouth the filter seems to be accepting the correct value (`$parent_file = 'charts'`), by the time the menu is being output, something else has changed it back (`$parent_file = 'edit-chart'`).

```
/**
 * Highlight the 'Charts' top level menue when viewing the 'Edit Chart' page
 */
function on_menu_parent($parent_file) {

    global $current_screen;

    $base = $current_screen->base;
    if($base == 'admin_page_edit-chart') :
        $parent_file = 'charts';
    endif;

    return $parent_file;

}
```

The filter, called from the Plugin Class constructor is this -

```
add_filter('parent_file', array(&$this, 'on_menu_parent'));
```

Does anybody know how to get this working correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If written the ["Current Admin Info"](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) plugin for exactly that reason: Find what you need, when you need it. It adds a help tab with all the currently available (contextual info).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This. This is very cool.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thanks :) Btw: It's extensible. So if you got other classes (a.k.a. Help Tabs), you want to incorporate, feel free to send me a pull request.

Comment: While I thank you for you answer, I don't understand how this can help me. I've tried to install it, as maybe I'm misunderstanding it's purpose, but with it active, no extra info is available in any of my help tabs?

Comment: @DavidGard You have "tried" to install it, or _did_ you install it? Are you saying, that you can't see the additional help tabs? Please clarify.

Comment: Installed and cannot see any additional help tabs. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidGard Please deactivate any other plugins and try it again. There might be some conflict. Then turn on one by one and retry each time. If you found the conflicting plugin, please tell me, so I can look up it's source and identify the conflict.